# Upper bound for $E[X^2 1_{|X| > v }]$

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, expected-value

Given a random variable $X$ such that for some $p$, we have
$$
|| X ||_{L_p} = (E |X|^p )^{1/p} \le C_p < \infty.
$$
Supposedly then the following statement is true: for any $v>0$

$$
E (X^2 1_{|X| > v}) \le \text{min} \left ( ||X||^2_{L_2}, \frac{||X||^p_{L_p}}{v^{p-2}} \right).
$$

For the first, I can see that

$$
E (X^2 1_{|X| > v}) \le E(X^2) = ||X||^2_{L_2},
$$

but how do we show the second upper bound?

Comment: Use $|X| 1_{|X|\gt v}\le \min(|X|,v).$

Comment: @whuber how can that be true? If $|X| > v$ then the LHS is $|X|$ and the RHS is $v$

Comment: Sorry -- I got things reversed.  But I hope the idea is clear: split the values of $|X|$ into those in $[0,v]$ and those in $(v,\infty)$ and apply the simplest, most obvious inequalities you can think of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $p > 2$, then
\begin{align}
\|X\|_p^p = E[|X|^p] \geq E[|X|^p1_{|X| > v}] 
= E\left[|X|^{p - 2 + 2}1_{|X| > v}\right] \geq v^{p - 2}E[X^21_{|X| > v}].
\end{align}

Rearranging terms gives you the desired inequality.

If $p \leq 2$, your "supposedly true" inequality is not true. For a counterexample, consider a discrete random variable $X$ with $P[X = 0] = P[X = 2] = P[X = -2] = 1/3$, and let $v = p = 1$. It is then easy to check that $E[X^21_{|X| > 1}] = 4 \times \frac{2}{3} = \frac{8}{3}$, which is greater than $E[|X|] = 2 \times \frac{2}{3} = \frac{4}{3}$.